# Is there a way to know if a range is a named range?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

Context: I am working on a Addin for Excel using Microsoft's "new" Office Javascript API.

So far, I am able to get the user's selection and a collection of named ranges in the worksheet with the code below:

```
const selectedRange = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
const namedRanges = context.workbook.names;
```

However, what I am trying to achieve is to check if the user's selection `selectedRange` is a named range in the worksheet and if so get that named range object.

I have not found any "built-in" way to do this so far and the only ideas I have would be a nightmare to implement or result in bad performance.

Is this even possible? What are your ideas?

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question.

You could use `getIntersectionOrNullObject` to detect whether your selection is in `namedRanges` or not. it can return address of the `selectedRange` in `getIntersectionOrNullObject` or it will return null object

Here is sample code:

```
  Excel.run(function (ctx) {

    const selectedRange = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();
    const namedRanges = ctx.workbook.names;

    var sheetName = "Sheet1";
    var rangeAddress = "A1:F8"; // replace to named range address
    // var rangeAddress = namedRanges.items[0].getRange();

    var range =
      ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheetName).getRange(rangeAddress).getIntersectionOrNullObject(selectedRange);

    range.load('address');

    console.log("test");
    return ctx.sync().then(function () {
      console.log("test2");

      console.log(range.address);  
    });
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
      console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
  });
```

the document can be found at 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#getintersection-anotherrange-

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this isn't really what I am trying to achieve. Furthermore, your solution assumes that the named range's name is known beforehand. In my situation, I will not know the name of the named range, infact, that is what I want to know when I select a range: is it a named range and if so, what is it's name.

Comment: You don't have to know the name of the namedItem, you could use context.workbook.names.items[i] to get all names in the scope of workbook.